# Get Background Image from PDF using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

Is it possible to get the background image as an image from a pdf using PDFBox from Apache?
I only get the images which are on the pages or can save the page as an image?

Alternate: Is it possible to delete all elements from a page to get the background image?

Comment: Are you sure the *background image* is a bitmap image to start with? Also there are not special "background images" and "on page images". Probably you should show your code. Also, if you *delete all elements from a page*, you delete all elements from a page and get an empty page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.